# Nailing down a definitive list of Data URL safe characters in 2020

Tags: character-set, data-uri, utf-8

I'm looking to find (or otherwise establish) an authoritative list of **Data URL Safe** characters in 2020.

I've found older references on the web regarding which characters may or may not be **Data URL Safe**, most notably this one from late 2012:

- [(Please) Stop Using Unsafe Characters in URLs](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/) (Dec 2012)

but I'm guessing it may be a little out of date given that it recommends encoding spaces and commas (?) and I'm fairly certain that these are both fairly safe to include in a **Data URL** today. (Although I may be wrong about this...)

Here is my current list of **Data URL Safe** characters:

- `A-Z`
- `a-z`
- `0-9`
- `.`
- `,`
- `;`
- `:`
- `/`
- `_`
- `=`
- `-`
- `~`
- `'`
- `[space]`

Are there any more **Data URL Safe** characters which ought to be on the list above but aren't?

Conversely, are there any characters on the list above which really are *not safe* to be included in a **Data URL**?

Comment: What makes you think that RFC3986 section 3 https://pretty-rfc.herokuapp.com/RFC3986 isn't current?

Comment: A list of allowed characters is explained there.  Why aren't you using that as your reference instead of asking people's opinions?

Comment: @Steve - I'm not seeing the list of allowed characters you are referring to. Please can you give the closest sub-heading in the document? Thanks.

Comment: Section 3 synopsis inc 3.2 - it includes the statement "A URI is composed from a limited set of characters consisting of digits, letters, and a few graphic symbols." and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 2397 - The "data" URL scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) says what characters are allowed in Data URIs:

> ```
> data       := *urlchar
> ```
>
> where "urlchar" is imported from RFC2396

RFC 2396 has been obsoleted by [RFC 3986 - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) so that should be consulted.  Unfortunately, it doesn't actually define "urlchars".  It says that the characters available for unreserved use within URIs are:

```
unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

And the characters may be used in URIs but which are reserved as delimeters with special meaning are:

```
 reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
 gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
 sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
               / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

It appears that when RFC 2397 says "urlchars" it means both the "reserved" and "unreserved" characters.    [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

> Note that this may include characters, such as colon, semicolon, and comma which are delimiters in the URI components preceding the data part.

The list you started with erroneously includes `[space]` which is not listed anywhere as a URI character.   Your list does not include several of the punctuation symbols which are all allowed.